# clarification on how rainbow tables use multiple reduction functions to avoid collisions

Tags: rainbow-table

I understand how Hellman's time-memory trade-off tables work by creating chains of hash and reduction function results and storing the last result after a number of operations. since the reduction function maps from hash space (crapton of characters) into password space (let's say up to 10 characters), it's obviouts we are going to have a ton of collisions.

Rainbow tables try to solve this by using multiple reduction functions. I dont understand How or why that helps.

[This wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table#Rainbow_tables) seems to try to put some light into it, but I just cant make sense of what it's trying to say.

> Rainbow tables effectively solve the problem of collisions with ordinary hash chains by replacing the single reduction function R with a sequence of related reduction functions R<sub>1</sub> through R<sub>k</sub>. In this way, for two chains to collide and merge they must hit the same value on the same iteration.

Comment: Please don't post text as images. Its hard (or for some, impossible) to read and search. Just copy paste the quote instead.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I think I figured it out.

I made an illustration since It seems to be the best way of explaining what's going on.

Rainbow tables use a different reduction function on each link in the chain (this can be viewed as a different function on each column, where chains are rows)

**In the following illustration**

- **H()** is the Hashing function
- **R()** is a common reduction function used on every link (not a rainbow table)
- **R1() to R3()** are different reduction functions on every link (Rainbow table)
- **A-Z** are plaintexts obtained by a reduction function
- **Hash1-5** are hashes obtained by the Hashing function

**In the illustration you will find:**

- What happens during a **collision** in a **Hellmans table** (the predecessor of the Rainbow table, uses a single reduction function R())
- What happens during a **collision** in a **Rainbow table** (identical to the Hellmans table, but uses different Reduction functions on each chain link)
- What happens during a **Collision occurring on the same spot** on a **Rainbow table** (It's statistically unlikely, but if this happens then the chains end up being identical, but since this does not happen often it's not that much of a concern)

[image]

Comment: Very helpful graphic! What are good/common reduction functions used in practice. Most examples just mention taking some characters of the hashed output, but I doubt that's actually useful in practice, is it?

Comment: Sorry, I barely even remember what I was asking.